# Basic CakePHP architecture: Accessing multiple controllers / models in one view

Tags: php, cakephp, architecture, cakephp-2.0

I started working with CakePHP recently and while the cookbook is not a bad resource, it doesn't really answer my very basic questions.

By default, CakePHP's architecture seems to think that you've got one View for one action in a Controller for one Model. But suppose I've got a typical Blog application, where a common view from the user's perspective consists of:

- The published article (action view() for model Article)
- A widget to write a comment for that article (action add() for model Comment)
- A list of comments by other users (action index() for model Comment)

This is a very common use-case, but currently I can't really grasp what's CakePHP's "intended" way of solving it. I'm thinking of:

- Having one Controller for the use-case above, which handles multiple Models.
- Having one Controller per Model, but having one View containing some kind of sub-views which are connected to different Controllers

The latter seems to be the cleaner approach to me, because it would allow to reuse the sub-views and avoid code-duplication in the Controllers, but from what I've read I'm not sure if CakePHP can actually do that. Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This is a very common use-case, but currently I can't really grasp what's CakePHP's "intended" way of solving it.

This is not specific to CakePHP but you'll have the same kind of "problem" in probably any MVC framework. It is all about proper [SoC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

> Having one Controller per Model, but having one View containing some kind of sub-views which are connected to different Controllers

That's close.

Usually you get all the data that is required to be displayed for a page within the action of that page. Attention: This doesn't mean to bloat the controller with hundreds of lines of code. You can fetch the comments through the articles association because one article has many comments - that's your association.

You can use [view cells](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/cells.html) for displaying content as well. I personally would prefer trying to get all the data without using a cell if possible. But that's a matter of taste I think.

The comment form would do a post to the comments controllers add action and redirect back to where the use came from.

You can write a component that serves as proxy and adds transparently an addComment and editComment "method" to your controller to make this easy to reuse and avoid code duplication. I'm not going to describe the whole way of doing it here, it's simply to long, but I guess you get the idea.

My personal favorite in the case of comments would be a CakePHP plugin for the comments with a RESTful API and a JS based frontend widget. basically a minimalistic clone of the popular Disqus widget. Just throw the widget into your page and get comments working in no time on any page in the most re-useable way. :)

Comment: You make some excellent points. I'm on CakePHP 2.x, so view cells don't seem to be available for me, which means I'd have to use Elements and requestAction(). I'm personally not a fan of adjusting the Controllers based on the View, because I feel it undermines the reason why we're using MVC in the first place. I'll leave the question open a little longer, maybe there are other views on the topic.